# Regex match if String has no alphanumic characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex expression that matches a string that has only non-alphanumic characters.

For example:

- `".."` would be `true`
- `".dds!f"` would be `false`
- and `"sdjhgfsjd"` would be `false`.

I have tried `str.matches("\\p{Punct}")` however this only seems to match single punctionation characters.  eg.  `".".matches("\\p{Punct}")` would be true but `"..".matches("\\p{Punct}")` would be false.

I suppose an equivalent question would also be to match if there is any alphanumeric character in the string.

Comment: Can't you do one that matches and put a `!` in front? Like `!stringVar.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]");`

Comment: First of all you need to add `+` to match one or more `\p{Punct}`. Second thing: what about white spaces (they are not alphanumeric but are also not `\p{Punct}`), should they be matched or not? Also should characters that are alphabetic in other languages beside English like `źźć` be matched or not?

Comment: Thanks Pshemo adding the + seemed to work.  What I meant was that if I could get an expression that matched on any alphanumeric character I could simply negate it and obtain the solution to my original question of matching on strings that have only non-alphanumeric characters.  Also in my particular use case there should be no whitespace or other language characters.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matches strings containing no letters or digits:

```
^[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/eqfthXddPb6Vwl-X)

And this matches strings with at least one letter or digit:

```
^.*[a-zA-Z0-9].*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wuDZ1FmIBoGMpf_8)

Please take a look through the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for some more helpful information.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can use

```
str.matches("\\P{Alnum}")
```

`Alnum` is shorter form of *alphabetic* and *numeric*. Also `\P{Alnum}` is negation of `\p{Alnum}`. So this regex will return true if string contains only one or more characters which are not alphanumeric. If you want to also accept empty strings change `+` to `*`.

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
\W
```

or

```
\W*
```

with .matches

Here is the documentation -> [Predefined Character Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html)

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
"[^A-Za-z0-9]*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't simply

```
[^A-Za-z0-9]*
```

work?