# Regular Expression for a string that contains one or more letters somewhere in it

Tags: java, regex

What would be a regular expression that would evaluate to true if the string has one or more letters anywhere in it.

For example:

`1222a3999` would be true

`a222aZaa`  would be true

`aaaAaaaa`  would be true

but:

`1111112())--` would be false

I tried: `^[a-zA-Z]+$` and `[a-zA-Z]+` but neither work when there are any numbers and other characters in the string.

Comment: `.*[a-zA-Z}.*`, assuming your string does not contain new lines

Comment: It should work even if the string does contain new lines.

Comment: Check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997855/regex-match-if-string-has-no-alphanumic-characters/22998120#22998120) in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997855/regex-match-if-string-has-no-alphanumic-characters)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`.*[a-zA-Z].*`

The above means one letter, and before/after it - anything is fine.

In java:

```
String regex = ".*[a-zA-Z].*";
System.out.println("1222a3999".matches(regex));
System.out.println("a222aZaa ".matches(regex));
System.out.println("aaaAaaaa ".matches(regex));
System.out.println("1111112())-- ".matches(regex));
```

Will provide:

```
true
true
true
false
```

as expected

Answer (score 4):

`^.*[a-zA-Z].*$`

Depending on the implementation, `match()` functions check if the *entire* string matches (which is probably why your `[a-zA-Z]` or `[a-zA-Z]+` patterns didn't work).

Either use `match()` with the above pattern or use some sort of `search()` method instead.

Answer (score 2):

This regexp should do it:

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

It matches as long as there's a single letter anywhere in the string, it doesn't care about any of the other characters.

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

should have worked as well, I don't know why it didn't for you.

Comment: Well, at least in java terminology - it does not *match*, it *contains* the stated regex.

Comment: Because `match` usually checks the entire string.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using NSPredicate (for iOS), I think it has to match the entire string, not just contain it.

Comment: If you need an answer specific to a particular language, you should say that in the question, and tag the question with the language.

Comment: I don't now Java, but it looks to me like you can make a `Matcher` from the regexp, and then use its `find()` method to find the pattern anywhere in the input.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Java and NSPredicate (a class in the iOS/Cocoa Objective-C framework) are mutually exclusive.  That's why I deleted the NSPredicate tag.  @codenamepenryn, what exactly are you using?

Comment: I'm using NSPredicate, but it's OK. One of the answers worked and I accepted it already.

Answer (score 1):

`.*[a-zA-Z]?.*`

Should get you the result you want.

The period matches any character except new line, the asterisk says this should exist zero or more times. Then the pattern [a-zA-Z]? says give me at least one character that is in the brackets because of the use of the question mark. Finally the ending .* says that the alphabet characters can be followed by zero or more characters of any type.

Comment: `?` isn't at least one, it's 0 or 1. So that regexp will match anything.

Comment: At least one is `+`. But you only need to match 1, you don't need to match more than 1.

Comment: Yeah, entered that way too fast. Thank you for the correction on my error.

Comment: Better than the accepted answer, since it explains what it's actually doing.